# What is the fastest way to get a property from an object after checking that the object isn't null?

Tags: c#, java, string, object, null

What is the fastest way (in terms of minimizing the amount of code statements) to get a property from an object after checking that the object isn't null?

```
string s = null;

if (null != myObject)
{
    s = myObject.propertyName;
}
```

Comment: Use ternary operator?
var s = myObject == null ? null : myObject.PropertyName
And it's not clear what do you mean under "fastest".

Comment: (commence war over name: "ternary" vs "conditional" operator...)

Comment: Do you mean simplest because this will not be the slowest portion of your code and you should need to worry about performance here.

Answer (score 2):

*For reference:* Wait for [future C# 6.0 feature](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated) for null checking with possible `?.` syntax:

```
string result = obj?.ToString();
```

*For now:* Use [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
string result = obj != null ? obj.ToString() : null;
```

Comment: At the moment, that remains a *possible* new syntax. It is not, for example, in the currently available roslyn builds. (\*cough\* conditional operator \*cough\*)

Answer (score 1):

C# does not have a null-propagating operator (although it has been discussed a few times). Frankly, "faster" is not likely to be a factor here, as it will typically end up in the same (or similar enough) IL, but I tend to use:

```
string s = myObject == null ? null : myObject.PropertyName;
```

Comment: I would put the condition into braces because this would lead into confusion: `string s = (myObject == null) ? null : myObject.PropertyName;`

Comment: @JohannesWanzek I'm not confused, and the compiler is not confused. If you prefer parentheses, by all means use them.

Comment: It's a common pattern to put conditions into brackets, so the developer directly identifies the meaning of this expression. But ok that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

the situation you describe is only one scenario where the operator is useful. It's also handy to replace constructs like this:

```
 if (value != null)
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return otherValue;
        }
```

Or

```
return value != null ? value : otherValue;
```

with

```
return value ?? otherValue;
```